# Kafka Connect JDBC db.timezone config

Tags: postgresql, db2, timezone, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to wrap my head around how the db.timezone property works on both the source and sink connectors.

For the source the docs say:

> Name of the JDBC timezone used in the connector when querying with time-based criteria. Defaults to UTC.

What does this actually mean? Is that supposed to be set to the timezone of my source database? I have a db that is set to eastern timezone. Do I need to set this to US/Eastern? If I don't what will it do?

On the sink side the docs say:

> Name of the JDBC timezone that should be used in the connector when inserting time-based values. Defaults to UTC.

Again what exactly does this mean. Does it use that to convert the all timestamps in your payload to the value you give here?

My specific problem is my source db has eastern timezone, but my sink db is set to UTC and I can't change it. How should I define these properties.

Also to add to this, I think it's slightly unrelated but I notice on my sink side the timestamps don't have all the decimals. But on both sides in have the timestamp columns set to timestamp(6). However on the sink side the decimal points always only just have 3 digits and the remaining 3 are all 0s. Why would this be?

Comment: What part of the docs are you quoting, on what product or spec? Provide links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the source code:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/source/JdbcSourceConnectorConfig.java#L805

to get a feeling on how the value you specify for the `db.timezone` configuration option will be used by the kafka-connect-jdbc connector.

I'd assume that for your source connector you should use

```
db.timezone=US/Eastern
```

> Name of the JDBC timezone used in the connector when querying with time-based > criteria. Defaults to UTC.
> What does this actually mean?

The `db.timezone` setting comes in handy when reading/writing data from databases which don't use UTC timezone for storing the date/time columns.

Since your sink database uses `UTC` timezone, there's no additional setting related to setting the timezone in your jdbc sink configuration.

Comment: My database is in US/Eastern time and my program is running in CST. After changing the db.timezone=US/Eastern in the Kafka Source JDBC connector configuration file. Now, I am seeing changes that are occuring in the database in the Kafka topic . Thank you Marius for the suggestion.